# Incorporating a COM DLL into C#

Tags: c#, com, vb6, com-interop

I'm having some problems incorporating a COM DLL into a C#.NET program. The DLL was given to me by a third party. It was done in VB6. Currently, this is the error I'm receiving.

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException was unhandled.
>   HResult=-2147221164 Message=Retrieving the COM class factory for
>   component with CLSID {46F5C9EE-D750-4740-    AFBD-682F1E097776} failed
>   due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception
>   from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).

It throws the exception when I try to create a new object from one of the classes in the DLL file.

I've tried registering the DLL with regsvr32.exe and using tlbimp.exe to create another DLL (which worked but gave me a tremendous amount of warnings). Everytime I've tried debugging my program I get some sort of exception.

Should I just give up and do this in VB6? I really don't want to...

Comment: have you tried looking at the dll with dependency walker? I usually find that tool rather useful when dealing with other people's dlls.

Comment: In their defense, the whole purpose of this project is to interface with another piece of software and provide the user with some form of automation. The original developers only provide a bit of VB6 example code for automating the whole process which is probably why he did what he did.

Comment: What are some errors you get other than the ones you mentioned?

Comment: did registration with `regsvr32` reported that it was succesful?

Comment: As of now, that's the only error. The other ones involved a COM exception.

Comment: Yes, regsvr32 said it was successful.

Comment: Also is the TLB short enough that you can post it?  It's very possible that the DLL exposes some strange types/interfaces that would be difficult (maybe impossible) to interop with in C#.

Comment: Dependency walker shows a question mark near MSVBVM60.DLL... I'm not quite sure what that DLL is or has to do with this project. Any ideas?

Comment: That is the VB6 runtime library and you need it on your machine, as the dll is a VB component

Comment: However, I would expect a different error in that case. If you lookup the CLSID `46F5C9EE-D750-4740-AFBD-682F1E097776` in registry, does it point to the dll as InprocServer32? Maybe your client code was built with earlier version and ProgIDs/CLSIDs were changed?

Comment: This is strange. I already have that file in C:\Windows\SysWOW64

Comment: No, the registry entries are fine... grr.

Comment: what platform is your C# app built against? what platform settings you have for projects? AnyCPU, x86?

Comment: If you change your platform settings to x86, does it work?

Comment: .NET 4.0. I just changed the target platform to x86 now I get this error: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146827949
  Message=Creating an instance of the COM component with CLSID {46F5C9EE-D750-4740-AFBD-682F1E097776} from the IClassFactory failed due to the following error: 800a0153 Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A0153.

Comment: It seems to me that your component is correctly instantiated now (you forgot to mention you was running this on 64-bit system), and now you have some component specific problem, but I am not 100% sure

Comment: Yes, sorry I forgot to mention it's a x64 system... any other ideas? I feel like I've tried everything.

Comment: It seems that the registration problem is solved. As the facility code of the new error is 10 (0xA) i.e. FACILITY_CONTROL which, AFAIK, is used by VB, I believe that this might be related to component implementation itself, which means that without code it is very hard to tell

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a DLL in which the thrid party VB6 DLL depends upon. This could be another VB6 DLL or another third party reference (or lower level DLL such as the VB runtime).

The best approach to resolve your issue would be to ask the third party provider which DLL(s) are required as dependencies. As a VB6 developer they should easily be able to answer the question versus you having to run something such as dependency walker which can easily lead you down the wrong path.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I solved the problem. The third party software that the COM DLL gives me access to requires a USB dongle to be inserted into the computer, otherwise it will only run in trial mode. This was prohibiting me from accessing the DLL functionality.